# Offline Access. Verifying Access Token?

Tags: php, facebook

I have offline access to post on a users wall, but before I post, is it possible to check if I actually have permission i.e. by verifying the access token or by using another solution?

Sometimes I am getting "Error processing Access Token" which makes me think the user has removed the application or denied access to post on their wall.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, though not with the new Graph API.

You'll need to use the [`users.hasAppPermission`](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Users.hasAppPermission) method of the old REST API to verify whether the user has granted you an extended permission.

Comment: Hmmm. Is there no other way of doing this?

I think I'm probably going to have to attach a try...catch block and ignore the exception. I know its not the best solution but going through the old API seems long winded.

Comment: The new SDK lets you call old API methods pretty easily.

Comment: @James Jeffery: Peter is right that you can call methods from the old API pretty easily with the new SDK, but you shouldn't count on them being available for long. I think it's perfectly reasonable to rely on exceptions in this case.